# Gazebo Harmonic : world SDF file uses file:/// prefix for paths instead of model://

Tags: gazebo, model, sdf, world

I'm facing an issue when saving a sdf world with Gazebo Harmonic. I import a model I created into Gazebo. It's located in GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH :

```
GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH=/home/arusso/dev/coupe/ws_0/src/champi_simulator/models
```

When I save the world, it appears in the world sdf as below :

```
<include>
  <uri>file:///home/arusso/dev/coupe/ws_0/src/champi_simulator/models/table_2024</uri>
  <name>table_2024</name>
  <pose>0 -0.31179749965667725 0 -1.5707959999999999 -4.568824318126933e-20 1.1541911114043286e-16</pose>
</include>
```

However, It could simply use the [more portable syntax using model://](https://gazebosim.org/api/gazebo/3.7/migrationsdf.html) :

```
<include>
  <uri>model://table_2024</uri>
  <name>table_2024</name>
  <pose>0 -0.31179749965667725 0 -1.5707959999999999 -4.583797889096051e-20 1.1541926087609363e-16</pose>
</include>
```

I can edit the sdf file manually, which works, but if I save again it falls back to absolute paths. Why does it do this ? I'd really want the world to use the model:// prefix so that my team can use the simulation more easily.